# How to import android.net.Uri in an Android Studio scratch file?

Tags: android, android-studio, scratch-file

I tried to run the following program in an Android Studio scratch file:

```kotlin
import android.net.Uri
println (Uri.encode("?"))
```

But it fails with the following error:

> Unresolved reference: android

But this seems to work:

```kotlin
import java.net.URLEncoder
println (URLEncoder.encode("?", Charsets.UTF_8.name()))
```

How to tell Android Studio about `android`?